# How to stay on run .jar file after exit the terminal via ssh in Linux?

Tags: java, ssh, jar

I want to run jar file from Linux terminal using ssh command. for that i am using bellow command

`screen -d -m -S minecraft java -jar myfile.jar` [OR] screen java -jar myfile.jar

its running fine upto detach/exit. After that its not working.

How can i achieve will run myfile.jar 24/7 after detach/exit?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't that actually be a linux command line question since it is not specific to java nor to ssh? Hint: run process in background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nohup screen -d -m -S minecraft java -jar myfile.jar` should help

Comment: its returned message "nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'". But its working until detach/exit. After that not working.

Comment: Voting not to delete, but you should add some explanation as to why this is the answer, talex.